# Trato de conectar mi app a firebase y aparece el error FirebaseOptions cannot be null when creating the default app

Tags: firebase

```
/// ESTE ES EL CODIGO///
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Material App Bar'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            child: Text('Hello World'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

/// ESTE ES EL ERROR ///

> Performing hot restart...
> Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...
> Restarted application in 1.590ms.
> Error: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.5.3/lib/src/firebase_core_web.dart:273:11
> options != null
> "FirebaseOptions cannot be null when creating the default app."
> at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:59737/dart_sdk.js:5067:11)
> at Object.assertFailed (http://localhost:59737/dart_sdk.js:4992:15)
> at firebase_core_web.FirebaseCoreWeb.new.initializeApp (http://localhost:59737/packages/firebase_core_web/firebase_core_web.dart.lib.js:252:42)
> at initializeApp.next ()
> at http://localhost:59737/dart_sdk.js:40568:33
> at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:59737/dart_sdk.js:40438:59)
> at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:59737/dart_sdk.js:35360:29)
> at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:59737/dart_sdk.js:35928:49)
> at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:59737/dart_sdk.js:35966:17)
> at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:59737/dart_sdk.js:35814:23)
> at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:59737/dart_sdk.js:35835:35)
> at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:59737/dart_sdk.js:40705:13)
> at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:59737/dart_sdk.js:40711:13)
> at http://localhost:59737/dart_sdk.js:36188:9

---

Este es mi Index.html
realicé el cambio pero sigue dando un error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    For more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

    This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
    the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
  -->
  <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="Red Social">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="faw">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>faw</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>
<body>
<script defer src="/__/firebase/9.6.1/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>
<!-- include only the Firebase features as you need -->
<script defer src="/__/firebase/9.6.1/firebase-auth-compat.js"></script>
<script defer src="/__/firebase/9.6.1/firebase-database-compat.js"></script>
<script defer src="/__/firebase/9.6.1/firebase-firestore-compat.js"></script>
<script defer src="/__/firebase/9.6.1/firebase-functions-compat.js"></script>
<script defer src="/__/firebase/9.6.1/firebase-messaging-compat.js"></script>
<script defer src="/__/firebase/9.6.1/firebase-storage-compat.js"></script>
<script defer src="/__/firebase/9.6.1/firebase-analytics-compat.js"></script>
<script defer src="/__/firebase/9.6.1/firebase-remote-config-compat.js"></script>
<script defer src="/__/firebase/9.6.1/firebase-performance-compat.js"></script>
<!--
  initialize the SDK after all desired features are loaded, set useEmulator to false
  to avoid connecting the SDK to running emulators.
-->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.20.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<!-- Firebase Auth SDK -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.20.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js?useEmulator=true"></script>
<script type="module">
  // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
  import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.1/firebase-app.js";
  // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: ""
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
   firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
</script>
  <!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
       application. For more information, see:
       https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
  <script>
    var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
    var scriptLoaded = false;
    function loadMainDartJs() {
      if (scriptLoaded) {
        return;
      }
      scriptLoaded = true;
      var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
      scriptTag.src = 'main.dart.js';
      scriptTag.type = 'application/javascript';
      document.body.append(scriptTag);
    }

    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      // Service workers are supported. Use them.
      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        // Wait for registration to finish before dropping the <script> tag.
        // Otherwise, the browser will load the script multiple times,
        // potentially different versions.
        var serviceWorkerUrl = 'flutter_service_worker.js?v=' + serviceWorkerVersion;
        navigator.serviceWorker.register(serviceWorkerUrl)
          .then((reg) => {
            function waitForActivation(serviceWorker) {
              serviceWorker.addEventListener('statechange', () => {
                if (serviceWorker.state == 'activated') {
                  console.log('Installed new service worker.');
                  loadMainDartJs();
                }
              });
            }
            if (!reg.active && (reg.installing || reg.waiting)) {
              // No active web worker and we have installed or are installing
              // one for the first time. Simply wait for it to activate.
              waitForActivation(reg.installing || reg.waiting);
            } else if (!reg.active.scriptURL.endsWith(serviceWorkerVersion)) {
              // When the app updates the serviceWorkerVersion changes, so we
              // need to ask the service worker to update.
              console.log('New service worker available.');
              reg.update();
              waitForActivation(reg.installing);
            } else {
              // Existing service worker is still good.
              console.log('Loading app from service worker.');
              loadMainDartJs();
            }
          });

        // If service worker doesn't succeed in a reasonable amount of time,
        // fallback to plaint <script> tag.
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (!scriptLoaded) {
            console.warn(
              'Failed to load app from service worker. Falling back to plain <script> tag.',
            );
            loadMainDartJs();
          }
        }, 4000);
      });
    } else {
      // Service workers not supported. Just drop the <script> tag.
      loadMainDartJs();
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Si seleccionaste un dispositivo? parece que lo estas ejecutando en chrome

Comment: si, lo estoy ejecutando en chrome es una applicacion para web

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya no tienes que poner las opciones de configuración en index.html. Edite su main.dart así y sus errores deberían desaparecer.

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
        options: FirebaseOptions(
           apiKey: "",
           authDomain: "",
           projectId: "",
           storageBucket: "",
           messagingSenderId: "1",
           appId: ""));
```

Comment: hice esa configuracion y ahora me da este error

**NoSuchMethodError: tried to call a non-function, such as null: 'dart.global.firebase.firestore'**

Comment: Intente poner su javascript dentro de la <head></head> en lugar del <body></body> de su index.html

Comment: Además, solo llame a Firebase.initilizeApp una vez. Ya sea en index.html o main.dart

Answer (score 2):

si estás tratando de correr en chrome tienes que poner esto en el index.html de la carpeta web antes del primer script que está ahí

```
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK (always required for using any Firebase service) -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.20.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <!-- Firebase Auth SDK -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.20.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script>
      // Your web app's Firebase configuration
      var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: '...',
        authDomain: '...',
        databaseURL: '...',
        projectId: '...',
        storageBucket: '...',
        messagingSenderId: '...',
        appId: '...',
      }
      // Initialize Firebase
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
    </script>
    <!-- END OF FIREBASE INIT CODE -->
```

colocas los datos necesarios que ahí te pide los cuales firebase te da y debería funcionar.

Comment: hice esta configuracion y ahora me da este error
**NoSuchMethodError: tried to call a non-function, such as null: 'dart.global.firebase.firestore'**